# Avoid Equatable and Hashable boilerplate, Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, swift4.2, equatable

On project we are using classes for model's layer and because of that I have to write code like this:

```
// MARK: - Hashable
extension Player: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.name)
    }
}
```

Can this boilerplate can be somehow avoided? Is it possible to implement that `Equatable` compare by `.hashValue` by default? Thanks.

Comment: You can use [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery) with a custom template and just extend your class to  `autoHashable` for example.

Comment: @EternalBlack In Swift 4.2 using Sourcery to generate Equatable and Hashable is just unnecessary. By the way, autogenerated code is not better that code written manually. The boilerplate is still there. Even bugs can be there in generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your custom template via Stencil markup language and autogenerate the code using the Sourcery library.

Or use the existing solutions (AutoEquatable, AutoHashable Sourcery templates).

And also you could write something like this:

```
protocol IHash: class { }

extension IHash where Self: Hashable {
    static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
}

class User: IHash, Hashable {
    var name: String = ""

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.name)
    }
}
```

It will help you to avoid duplication in different classes.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, that was exactly what I needed

Comment: No, comparing just the hash value in `==` is **wrong.**

Answer (score 7):

This is wrong, and it would make no sense that the compiler synthesizes it automatically:

```
static func == (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}
```

Identical objects must have the same hash value, but not the other way around: Distinct objects *can* have the same hash value.

Concretely, in your example: The name is a string and there are infinitely many different strings, but only 2<sup>64</sup> different hash values. So there must be two different strings with the same hash value.

If all stored properties are `Hashable` then the compiler can synthesize the conformance for you completely. For example

```
struct Player : Equatable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    var score: Int
}
```

Here two players are “identical” if they have the same name and the same score.

If there are non-hashable properties, or if you want to customize the concept of identity then you have to override `==` *and* `hash(into)` accordingly. The hash function should use the same properties which determine the identity in `==`. For example

```
struct Player : Equatable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    var score: Int

    static func == (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.name)
    }
}
```

Now two players are “identical” if they have the same name.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why my implementation of Equtable is wrong, can you please show example when it might lead to unexpected behavior?

Comment: @BohdanSavych: The name is a *string* and  there are infinitely many different strings, but only 2^64 different hash values. So there must be two different strings with the same hash value.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following is wrong and the reason is Hash collisions

```swift
static func == (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}
```

Hash was invented as a 'fast' way to compare objects.
If 2 objects have different hashes it is **Guaranteed** that they are different.

**But if they have same hashes we are not sure if they are the same.**

So `static func == (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool` is needed as a fallback method to use when hashes are the same in order to make sure objects are indeed the same.

So, if you use `.hashvalue` as implementation then sometimes you will get a false result because of the hash collision.

To accelerate the implementation of the Hashable protocol I recommend you start using sourcery to your project.