# Enum as a key for dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, hash, enums

I have a dictionary

```
var observers: [ObservingType: [MessageObserverManager?]] = .init()
```

as a key I use here enum, but for some reasons it doesn't work, dictionary doesn't create any object with these keys.

```
enum ObservingType: Hashable {
case messages(codeId: Int, codeTwoId: Int)
case allMessages
case threadMessages(otherId: Int)

static func == (lhs: ObservingType, rhs: ObservingType) -> Bool {
    return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
}

func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    switch self {
    case .messages(let codeId, let codeTwoId):
        hasher.combine(codeId)
        hasher.combine(codeTwoId)
        hasher.combine(1000 / Int.random(in: 1...25))

    case .allMessages:
        hasher.combine(100000 / Int.random(in: 1...25))

    case .threadMessages(let otherId):
        hasher.combine(otherId)
        hasher.combine(100000000 / Int.random(in: 1...25))
    }
}
```

Cold you advice whats wrong with enum?

guard observers[.allMessages]?.isEmpty ?? false else {
        observers[.allMessages]?.append(observer)

```
    return
}

observers[.allMessages] = [observer]
```

here is the code that I use to add values, and the issue was that I didnt create those array, so the reason wasnt in the enum, sorry and thanks for help!

Comment: Show code demonstrating the issue with the dictionary.

Comment: And what is the purpose of mixing random values into the hash? That definitely violates the contract that equal values must have the same hash.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56540417/1187415.

Comment: Note that the both `==` and `hash(into:)` can be synthesized *automatically* by the compiler.

Comment: @Martin R, thanks for you comments, I really implemented hashable in wrong way. I deleted all and compiler synthesized automatically, but the main reason was that I didnt create an array where i planned to add objects. Thanks ones again!

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `==` is incorrect. Do not compare hash values. Compare the actual values. Remember, two unequal values are allowed to have the same hash value.

Your implementation of `hash` should not be making use of random numbers. Remove those lines. The hash value for a given value needs to be steady (at least during a single execution of the app). You can't lookup values in a dictionary of the hash of the keys keep changing.

The simplest solution, in this case, is to let the compiler generate both `==` and `hash(into:)`. Then your code becomes:

```
enum ObservingType: Hashable {
    case messages(codeId: Int, codeTwoId: Int)
    case allMessages
    case threadMessages(otherId: Int)
}
```

It's much simpler and you can now use the `enum` as keys for a dictionary.

Comment: Or remove both implementations and let the compiler synthesize them.

Comment: @rmaddy thank you, you really helped, but the main reason was that I didnt create an array and added objects to nil. Thanks!